# Get specific value from Object in spring controller

Tags: java, spring

I have a Student Class, `StudentDao` Class, `StudentDetails` Class and `StudentController`
Student Class have following instances:

```
 private String studentId;
 private String studentName;
 private String studentGrade;
```

`StudentDao` gets these details from DB, `StudentDetails` Class returns a list of these details in following method:-

```
public List<Student> getSpecificStudentInfo(String studentId)
{
    List<Student> studentInfo=studentDao.getSpecificStudentInfo(studentId);     
    return studentInfo;

}
```

In my controller I use HashMap to get student details like

```
public Map<String, Object> referenceData(HttpServletRequest req)throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    String studentId=req.getParameter("studentId");
    Map<String, Object> studentRecord = new HashMap<String, Object>();
studentRecord.put("students",studentDetails.getSpecificStudentInfo(studentId));
    return studentRecord;
}
```

I m able to display these values in `Jsp` using `students.studentName`, `students.studentGrade`, etc. which is 1 requirement.

But my problem is that I want to use `studentName` and `studentGrade` further in my controller in `referenceData` method (before the return statement ofcourse) but I m not getting it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think that i did understand your question. in referenceData, you have studentId already from request. You could still extract grade using a loop over list.

```
public Map<String, Object> referenceData(HttpServletRequest req)throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    String studentId=req.getParameter("studentId");
    Map<String, Object> studentRecord = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    List<Student> listOfStudents = studentDetails.getSpecificStudentInfo(studentId); 
    String studentGrad = getGradeFor(studentId); 
studentRecord.put("students",listOfStudents);
    return studentRecord;
}
/* check nulls, empty list etc. */
public String getGradeFor(List<Student> listOfStudent, String id) {
       for (Student student: listOfStudent) {
            if (student.getId().equals(id)) return student.getGrade();
       }
       return null;
}
```

or you could build your database query more effectively and thus you get only one object in your list. that will be the student which you are looking for.